# Programa que le N numeros e printa a media, fim da leitura ocorre ao se ler um valor negativo

Tags: c

To com a seguinte questão a resolver, preciso criar um progrma em c que le n numeros inteiros positivos calcule e exiba a media artimetica destes, a condição de parada deste laço e a inserção de um numero negativo, eu fiz o seguinte codigo, mas sempre ele retorna como resultado 1 não importa os valores usados(sim ja ate setei tudo como float da 1 assim mesmo, ta duplicada nada, não tem nada aqui parecido com este problema), oque estou fazendo errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n,s,c;
    float m;

    do{
        printf("Digite um valor: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        s= s+n;
        c++;
    }while(n>0);
    m=s/c;
    printf("A media dos valores digitados foi: %d", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ja editei a pergunta.

Comment: Faça a conversão adequada: m = (float)s / c;

Comment: Adiantou nada fazer essa conversão o resultado exibido ainda e 1

Comment: Você se esqueceu de inicializar as varáveis c e s com zero.

Comment: Deu a mesma coisa

Comment: no `printf` tem `%d` e para escrever o valor de m é `%f`

Comment: e finalmente foi, muito obrigado, eu ia passar o dia inteiro matutando no mesmo problema